# How do i add CORS to "/profile" endpoint exposed by spring data rest

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, spring-data-rest

I am getting the below error while trying to access the "/profile" endpoint exposed by spring-data-rest, from a react client. I have enabled CORS at the repository, but still getting the error, while I'm able to access "http://localhost:8083/merchants". Thanks in advance.

**Error:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8083/profile/merchants' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to add a `@CrossOrign("*")` annotation above the controller class.

**edit**
Another approch is to enable CORS globally, by exposing this bean:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // Don't do this in production, use a proper list  of allowed origins
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is there is no explicit controller class and Spring-data-rest automatically generates the endpoints for the repository. In this case i am not sure where is the controller class for the "/profile" endpoint

Comment: @SumanMondal I've added an edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks the problem is resolved now after enabling the CORS globally